# Python Flask - Building the Server as Executable (Py2exe)

Tags: python, flask, py2exe, setup.py, software-distribution

I have a flask project, everything appears to be working fine. When using py2exe to build the package, (target server is a windows server ugh), the executable can execute, but leaves me with a `ImportError: No module named 'jinja2.ext'`

I have the module, and the website works fine with no ImportError when not executing from the .exe

I am pretty new at packaging and delivering, and not sure whats wrong with the setup that is causing the break from .py -> .exe conversion.

### Setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

import py2exe



NAME = "WorkgroupDashboard"
VERSION = "1.0"



setup(
    name=NAME,
    version=VERSION,
    description="Provides real time ISIS connection data",
    long_description="",
    # Get strings from http://www.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=list_classifiers
    classifiers=[],
    author="Test User",
    author_email='',
    url='',
    license='Free',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['ez_setup', 'examples', 'tests']),
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
    install_requires=[
        'flask >= 0.10.1',
        'SQLAlchemy>=0.6'
    ],
    console=['DashboardBack.py']
)
```

The idea is in order to turn the server on, just execute the .exe. Server will not have python on it. I am using Python 3.4 64 bit.

Edit: build cmd = `python setup.py py2exe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out it seems, Setup commands go inside the py2exe optuons=[]

Working Setup.py

```
__author__ = ''


import sys
from glob import glob # glob will help us search for files based on their extension or filename.
from distutils.core import setup # distutils sends the data py2exe uses to know which file compile
import py2exe

data_files = []
setup(
    name='WorkgroupDashboard',
    console=['DashboardBack.py'], # 'windows' means it's a GUI, 'console' It's a console program, 'service' a Windows' service, 'com_server' is for a COM server
    # You can add more and py2exe will compile them separately.
    options={ # This is the list of options each module has, for example py2exe, but for example, PyQt or django could also contain specific options
        'py2exe': {
            'packages':['jinja2'],
            'dist_dir': 'dist/test', # The output folder
            'compressed': True, # If you want the program to be compressed to be as small as possible
            'includes':['os', 'logging', 'yaml', 'flask', 'sqlalchemy'], # All the modules you need to be included,  because py2exe guesses which modules are being used by the file we want to compile, but not the imports
        }
    },

    data_files=data_files # Finally, pass the
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd convert mine to EXE and deploy is over a host. Just get "Auto Py To Exe" application. Download it locally. Open the app, insert your project location, do some setup if you want, and then click "Convert". There you go. Flask in EXE format. Plug-in anywhere that you like without the need to have Python Interpreter.